# Non native speaker poetry help

Tags: poetry

[Question about poetic sensibilities in “wann” vs “wenn”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/66133/question-about-poetic-sensibilities-in-wann-vs-wenn/66143#66143)

Link to previous question.

I am trying to say, poetically, that this woman loves singing so much it’s what keeps her living.

Would I say that as “Beim singen, lebt sie.” ? Or “Als sie singt, lebt sie.” Or another way entirely?

Comment: You can say: Beim Singen, lebt sie or Wenn sie singt, lebt sie. You can't say Als sie singt. That's not German. An entirely other way is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are not writing a poem. If you did, the rhyme would be very important and you don't provide it in your question.

["Der Gesang ist ihr Lebenselixier."](https://www.google.com/search?q=der+gesang+ist+ihr+lebenselixier) (*Singing is her elixir of life.*) is a rather common and poetic phrase in German.

Comment: "Singen ist ihr Leben" would be the normal phrase but this answer gives a really good poetic one.